# Signed circular-linear correlation or covariance?

Tags: regression, correlation, covariance, covariance-matrix, circular-statistics

In my recent project, I am implementing an adaptive MCMC procedure for a set of variables, some of which are linear (e.g., temperature in Celsius), some of which are circular (e.g., direction in angles). I figures the best way to calculate the covariance matrix would be through standard deviations and a correlation matrix:

$$C=\left[\matrix{\sigma^{-1}_X \\ \sigma^{-1}_{\Theta}}\right]\bf{R}\left[\matrix{\sigma^{-1}_X & \sigma^{-1}_{\Theta}}\right]$$

where $\bf{R}$ is the correlation matrix between the two random variables, $\sigma^{-1}_X$ is the inverse of the standard deviation of $X$, and $\sigma^{-1}_{\Theta}$ is the inverse of the circular standard deviation of $\Theta$. Both of the standard deviations are fairly easy to compute, which leaves me with finding the correlation matrix. To calculate $\bf{R}$, the tricky part is finding the correlation between the  circular and linear variables. I found [this tutorial](https://jdblischak.github.io/fucci-seq/circ-simulation-correlation.html#circular-linear-correlation), which gives the following expression for this linear-circular correlation:

$$R^2=\frac{r_{xc}^2+r_{xs}^2-2r_{xc}r_{xs}r_{cs}}{1-r_{cs}^2}$$

where

$$r_{xc}=corr(x,cos(\theta))$$
$$r_{xs}=corr(x,sin(\theta))$$
$$r_{cs}=corr(sin(\theta),cos(\theta))$$

However, it appears to me that this correlation is not signed. That is to say, I can only estimate whether a correlation exists, but not whether it is positive or negative. Do I see this right? Is there an alternative to get a signed correlation between linear and circular variables, or to calculate the covariance between them?

Comment: For what purpose are you attempting to construct a covariance matrix and why are you trying to do that with correlations?  This information is essential for understanding whether $R^2$ will even be meaningful in your application and for identifying a suitable way to measure the associations among your variables.

Comment: I would like to implement the adaptive Metropolis algorithm (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-7/issue-2/An-adaptive-Metropolis-algorithm/bj/1080222083.full), a MCMC algorithm which relies on estimates of the chain's covariance matrix to adjust its proposal density. I haven't found information yet on how to get such a covariance matrix if it includes both linear and circular variables, so this above is my attempt at cobbling together an approach.